# Is it common to debate which prophet is more significant?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophets, prophet-isa

I was watching a Turkish soap opera called [*Magnificent Century*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhte%C5%9Fem_Y%C3%BCzy%C4%B1l). A preacher in the series was saying that Jesus (PBUH) was more significant than Mohammed (PBUH). The Sultan ordered people to prove that the preacher was wrong and then kill him.
But the Sultan's priests had failed to prove that twice already.

The series is made by Muslims and is entirely about Turkish Muslims. I do not understand the purpose of the debates shown.

Is it common in Islam to debate who is more significant?

Comment: Please compose your question properly before posting it. This is a wiki type QA website and a post may sometimes lose its meaning in the revision process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would refer you to the following verse of the Holy Quran.

> آمَنَ الرَّسُولُ بِمَا أُنزِلَ إِلَيْهِ مِن رَّبِّهِ وَالْمُؤْمِنُونَ كُلٌّ آمَنَ بِاللّهِ وَمَلآئِكَتِهِ وَكُتُبِهِ وَرُسُلِهِ لاَ نُفَرِّقُ بَيْنَ أَحَدٍ مِّن رُّسُلِهِ وَقَالُواْ سَمِعْنَا وَأَطَعْنَا غُفْرَانَكَ رَبَّنَا وَإِلَيْكَ الْمَصِيرُ
>
> [link](http://tanzil.net/#2:285)
>
> The Messenger has believed in what was revealed to him from his Lord, and [so have] the believers. All of them have believed in Allah and His angels and His books and His messengers, [saying], **"We make no distinction between any of His messengers."** And they say, "We hear and we obey. [We seek] Your forgiveness, our Lord, and to You is the [final] destination." ( Quran 2:285 )

The reason the quran makes us say this is because these debates will never end and are not fruitful in any way.

In my opinion,  Muslims and Christians are not in a position to judge between the messengers(Peace Be Upon Them)

Comment: The apostle believes in what has been revealed to him from his Lord, and (so do) the believers; they all believe in Allah and His angels and His books and His apostles; We make no difference between any of His apostles; and they say: We hear and obey, our Lord! Thy forgiveness (do we crave), and to Thee is the eventual course.